# 2 column css3 setup with variable height and object inside vertically positioned

Tags: html, css, position

So here is the deal i have two columns. in each column there is a div that will have an image and a grouping of text. Now the sizes of the images are variable and so will the text that follows. But i want the image to be vertically and center aligned in its div.

Below i have my attempt but i think either general logic is wrong i may be over simplifying or not thinking this through enough.

Here is my jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bardsworth/hbuMy/1/

```
#collums {

text-align: left;

margin: 10px auto;
width:800px; /*must set the width */
}
/* EVERY DIV */
#collums div{
width:300px;
height:100px; /*i'd like not to have to set the height*/
margin-top:20px;
}
#collums div img{
float:left;
}
#columns div p{
text-align: left;

font-size: 13px;
padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
width: 75%;
float: right;
}
<div id="collums">
<div>
    <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" width="86" height="52">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" width="86" height="25">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" width="86" height="70">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" width="86" height="25">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

Comment: for height:100px; /*i'd like not to have to set the height*/, use overflow:hidden; if you do not want to specify height. However, this will displace the layout of odd left and even right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "But I want the image to be vertically and center aligned in its div."

So, I have done both. One with image aligned horizontally along the box. And another align vertically against the text on the right.

As I have mentioned before, if you don't want to specify height, you can use overflow:hidden.

Made a jsfiddle for the image aligned vertically/horizontally : http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/hbuMy/2/

I notice all the images are the same in width - which makes the css a little easier since I can put an exact number to the left of the `<p>` tags to create space for the image which is vertically middle aligned.

For horizontal:

```
#collums .horz img{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

For vertical:

```
#columns .vert {
    display:table;
}

#columns .vert .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: the vertical formatting is exactly what i need! Now my next question is how can i have each column's content flow more naturally. In other words i want the spacing between each div in each column to be equidistant. I'm thinking i should rethink this and use an unordered list instead. T

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aAPY2/. It uses Jquery. So be careful because it can slow down your site if it is used a lot. I have no idea how to do this with `css`. That would be ideal!